# Accessing cookie data in nodejs server

Tags: node.js

I am trying to access a cookie data in nodejs server that I sent from my nodejs server for an earlier request but when I try to access it using `req.headers.cookie` I am getting an encrypted string, I have been able to separate the encrypted cookie string like this{"cookie-name": "encrypted string"}, but I don't know how to get my data back, can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this package to manage cookies: [cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies)

Here is a small example taken from the official documentation:

```
var http = require('http')
var Cookies = require('cookies')
 
// Optionally define keys to sign cookie values
// to prevent client tampering
var keys = ['keyboard cat']
 
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  // Create a cookies object
  var cookies = new Cookies(req, res, { keys: keys })
 
  // Get a cookie
  var lastVisit = cookies.get('LastVisit', { signed: true })
 
  // Set the cookie to a value
  cookies.set('LastVisit', new Date().toISOString(), { signed: true })
 
  if (!lastVisit) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
    res.end('Welcome, first time visitor!')
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
    res.end('Welcome back! Nothing much changed since your last visit at ' + lastVisit + '.')
  }
})
 
server.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Visit us at http://127.0.0.1:3000/ !')
})
```

Comment: I am receiving a request with cookie, and i have to get data back from that cookie, how can i do that